# Populate a text box based on drop down value from a sharepoint List

Tags: jquery, content-editor-web-part

I have a List B that has a look up column "State" to a column "State" in List A .List A has corresponding column "City" to each state(unique combination) .
While adding new item in List B , State is a drop down which is populated from List A . I have a textbox "City" which should be populated based on the drop down "State" value from List A .

How can i implement it using Jquery . I tried to implement this using SPService . Can you please share some code sample .

Regards,
Grigory

Comment: Is customizing Form is an option?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an hidden drop down which gets populated based on SPServices.cascading feature.
On index change of hidden dropdown - populate the value in text box (using ontextchanged function)

Answer (score 0):

SPServices have a cool feature called Cascaded-Dropdowns - have a look here http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Cascaded drop downs wont work here as i need to populate a text box on drop down change event . Both drop down and text boxe's value exist in a different list .

Answer (score 0):

here is the link that displays a text in the text box based on the values selected from the drop down box.
http://coresharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-spservices-to-query-list-in.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ok i will make sure of it